# How to use right syntax to pass data between routing pages in jQuery based single page application?

Tags: jquery, routes, single-page-application, router

Sorry for my grammar, please correct me if I have any mistakes.

I am currently applying to a small SPA projects with **spa-master**

[spa-master - github](https://github.com/pangyongsheng/spa).

[spa-master - Detailed Description](https://www.cnblogs.com/pangys/p/8648485.html#commentform)

[vipspa - Routing source of spa-master - Pure front-end routing solution](https://github.com/wikieswan/vipspa)

The spa-master is very simple for me, also compatible with JQuery, saved me a lot of learning time( compared to other SPA framework React, Vue... ).

At the moment, I have an application question about routing page, can anyone give me some guidance?

**The usage scenario is:**

1. User input some information( time, place... ) with form on page A,
2. After clicking the button( submit or next ), show the information on page B.

**Related operations are described here:**

https://www.cnblogs.com/pangys/p/8648485.html#commentform

**Url - pass parameters**

Send parameter

```
Location.hash = router.stringify('home',{name:'Jack'});
```

Get parameters

```
Var obj = router.parse();
```

**Param - pass parameters**

Send parameter

```
Var msg = {
        'id': 'home_msg',
        'content': {
             Name: "Jack",
             Age: "18"
        }
};
router.setMessage(msg);
```

Get parameters

```
Var param = router.getMessage('home_msg');
Console.log(param);
```

My question is - **how to use the right syntax to reach these functions?**

**Update 2019/3/1/20:21**

[Webpage Link - The progress I have tried so far](http://wangzhaoyu.com/test/spa-master-test/)

Thank you again for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a feasible way to pass parameters, but not using the original author's syntax, use the jQuery syntax instead.

The workable example has been updated to the original address, you can check it from here.

[Workable Example - Pass data between routing pages with jQuery](http://wangzhaoyu.com/test/spa-master-test/)